# Kubernetes : kube-dns service not accessible via ClusterIP

Tags: linux, kubernetes, kubeadm, ipvs

Following an upgrade to v1.19.7 with `kubeadm`, my pods are unable to request the `kube-dns` service via the service's ClusterIP. When using the `kube-dns` pod IP address instead, DNS resolution works.

`kube-dns` pods are up and running:

```
$ kubectl get pods -n kube-system -l k8s-app=kube-dns
NAME                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
coredns-7674cdb774-2m58h   1/1     Running   0          33m
coredns-7674cdb774-x44b9   1/1     Running   0          33m
```

logs are clear:

```
$ kubectl logs coredns-7674cdb774-2m58h -n kube-system
.:53
[INFO] plugin/reload: Running configuration MD5 = 7442f38ca24670d4af368d447670ad91
CoreDNS-1.7.0
linux/amd64, go1.14.4, f59c03d
[INFO] 127.0.0.1:40705 - 31415 "HINFO IN 7224361654609676299.2243479664305694168. udp 57 false 512" NXDOMAIN qr,rd,ra 132 0.003954173s
```

kube-dns service is exposed:

```
$ kubectl get svc  -n kube-system
NAME       TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                  AGE
kube-dns   ClusterIP   10.96.0.10   <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP   301d
```

endpoints are also configured:

```
$ kubectl describe endpoints kube-dns --namespace=kube-system
Name:         kube-dns
Namespace:    kube-system
Labels:       k8s-app=kube-dns
              kubernetes.io/cluster-service=true
              kubernetes.io/name=KubeDNS
Annotations:  endpoints.kubernetes.io/last-change-trigger-time: 2021-01-19T14:23:13Z
Subsets:
  Addresses:          10.44.0.1,10.47.0.2
  NotReadyAddresses:  <none>
  Ports:
    Name     Port  Protocol
    ----     ----  --------
    dns-tcp  53    TCP
    dns      53    UDP
    metrics  9153  TCP

Events:  <none>
```

here is my coredns ConfigMap:

```
$ kubectl describe cm -n kube-system coredns
Name:         coredns
Namespace:    kube-system
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>

Data
====
Corefile:
----
.:53 {
    log
    errors
    ready
    health
    kubernetes cluster.local in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa {
       pods insecure
       fallthrough in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa
       ttl 30
    }
    prometheus :9153
    forward . /etc/resolv.conf
    cache 30
    loop
    reload
    loadbalance
}

Events:  <none>
```

on workers, kube-proxy is running:

```
$ kubectl get pods -n kube-system -o wide --field-selector spec.nodeName=ccqserv202
NAME               READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE    IP              NODE         NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
kube-proxy-8r65s   1/1     Running   0          78m    10.158.37.202   ccqserv202   <none>           <none>
weave-net-kvnzg    2/2     Running   0          6h3m   10.158.37.202   ccqserv202   <none>           <none>
```

networking between pods is working, as I am able to communicate between pods running on separate nodes (here, `dnsutils` runs on node `ccqserv202`, while `10.44.0.1` is the pod IP address from `coredns-7674cdb774-x44b9`, running on node `ccqserv223`).

```
$ kubectl exec -i -t dnsutils -- ping 10.44.0.1
PING 10.44.0.1 (10.44.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.44.0.1: seq=0 ttl=64 time=2.101 ms
64 bytes from 10.44.0.1: seq=1 ttl=64 time=1.184 ms
64 bytes from 10.44.0.1: seq=2 ttl=64 time=1.107 ms
^C
--- 10.44.0.1 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 1.107/1.464/2.101 ms
```

I am using "ipvs" as kube-proxy mode (although I can confirm the exact same behavior happens when using "iptables" or "userspace" modes).

Here is my `ipvsadm -Ln` on node `ccqserv202`:

```
$ ipvsadm -Ln 
IP Virtual Server version 1.2.1 (size=4096)
Prot LocalAddress:Port Scheduler Flags
  -> RemoteAddress:Port           Forward Weight ActiveConn InActConn
TCP  10.46.128.0:30040 rr
TCP  10.96.0.1:443 rr
  -> 10.158.37.223:6443           Masq    1      0          0         
  -> 10.158.37.224:6443           Masq    1      0          0         
  -> 10.158.37.225:6443           Masq    1      1          0         
TCP  10.96.0.10:53 rr
TCP  10.96.0.10:9153 rr
TCP  10.97.147.126:2746 rr
TCP  10.100.162.140:9000 rr
TCP  10.101.126.110:5432 rr
TCP  10.109.184.125:4040 rr
TCP  10.110.163.112:9090 rr
TCP  10.110.215.252:8443 rr
TCP  10.158.37.202:30040 rr
TCP  127.0.0.1:30040 rr
TCP  134.158.237.2:30040 rr
UDP  10.96.0.10:53 rr
```

as you can see, then are no realservers configured under `10.96.0.10` virtual addresses, but there are under `10.96.0.1` (which corresponds to the `kubernetes` API service).

I am able to open a connection to `10.96.0.1` on port 443

```
$ kubectl exec -i -t dnsutils -- nc -vz 10.96.0.1 443
10.96.0.1 (10.96.0.1:443) open
```

I am able to open a connection to `10.44.0.1` on port 53

```
$ kubectl exec -i -t dnsutils -- nc -vz 10.44.0.1 53
10.44.0.1 (10.44.0.1:53) open
```

it evens resolves!

```
$ kubectl exec -i -t dnsutils -- nslookup kubernetes.default 10.44.0.1
Server:     10.44.0.1
Address:    10.44.0.1#53

Name:   kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local
Address: 10.96.0.1
```

but this does not work when I use `kube-dns` ClusterIP 10.96.0.10

```
$ kubectl exec -i -t dnsutils -- nc -vz 10.96.0.10 53
command terminated with exit code 1
```

```
$ kubectl exec -i -t dnsutils -- nslookup kubernetes.default 10.96.0.10
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

here is `dnsutils` `resolv.conf` file:

```
$ kubectl exec -i -t dnsutils -- cat /etc/resolv.conf
search default.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local xxxxx.fr
nameserver 10.96.0.10
options ndots:5
```

finally, when I try manually adding realservers to `ipvs` on the node,

```
$ ipvsadm -a -u 10.96.0.10:53 -r 10.44.0.1:53 -m
```

`kube-proxy` detects it and immediately cleans it:

```
I0119 16:17:27.062890       1 proxier.go:2076] Using graceful delete to delete: 10.96.0.10:53/UDP/10.44.0.1:53
I0119 16:17:27.062906       1 graceful_termination.go:159] Trying to delete rs: 10.96.0.10:53/UDP/10.44.0.1:53
I0119 16:17:27.062974       1 graceful_termination.go:173] Deleting rs: 10.96.0.10:53/UDP/10.44.0.1:53
```

also, we can see with `tcpdump` that DNS requests from `dnsutils` to `10.96.0.10` are NOT rewritten to `10.44.0.1` or `10.47.0.2` as they should be with `ipvs`

```
    10.46.128.8.53140 > 10.96.0.10.domain: [bad udp cksum 0x94f7 -> 0x12c4!] 4628+ A? kubernetes.default.default.svc.cluster.local. (62)
16:27:56.950950 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 45349, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 90)
    10.46.128.8.53140 > 10.96.0.10.domain: [bad udp cksum 0x94f7 -> 0x12c4!] 4628+ A? kubernetes.default.default.svc.cluster.local. (62)
16:27:56.951321 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 59811, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 70)
```

a tcpdump on kube-dns pods on the other side shows that these requests never arrive.

I've now spent a full day trying to understand what is happening and how to fix, and I am now  running out of ideas. Any help would be very much welcome.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/ unfortunately did not help.

Thank you!

**tl;dr:** DNS resolution in the Kubernetes cluster does not work when using the `kube-dns` service ClusterIP, although I am able to resolve when using the `kube-dns` pods IP address. I would think something is wrong with my `kube-proxy` configuration, but I can't find what.

Comment: Hi sqw, welcome to S.F. What CNI provider are you using, and have you checked that its Pods are in good shape? Actually, related to that: is kube-dns the only Service IP that is messed up?

Comment: Thanks @mdaniel, I am using weave as CNI. All weave pods are healthy, and logs look good. I actually didn't try before but I just did: other services are messed up when I try to access them via their ClusterIP, whereas direct pod access is OK.

Comment: Hi @sqw, have you tried to use other CNI?

Comment: Hi @Jakub, I haven't try with other CNI as I hoped to understand what was wrong with this configuration, but in the end I redeployed the whole cluster from scratch, and the issue is now gone... I'd still be interested to know if other people had similar issues with similar configurations though

Answer (score 0):

i met similar phenomena.
repeat netcat dsn svc cluster ip port 53 sometimes unreachable

```
root@cluster0:~# nc -vzw 3  10.96.0.10 53
Connection to 10.96.0.10 53 port [tcp/domain] succeeded!
root@cluster0:~# nc -vzw 3  10.96.0.10 53
Connection to 10.96.0.10 53 port [tcp/domain] succeeded!
root@cluster0:~# nc -vzw 3  10.96.0.10 53
^[[Anc: connect to 10.96.0.10 port 53 (tcp) timed out: Operation now in progress
root@cluster0:~# nc -vzw 3  10.96.0.10 53
Connection to 10.96.0.10 53 port [tcp/domain] succeeded!
root@cluster0:~# nc -vzw 3  10.96.0.10 53
Connection to 10.96.0.10 53 port [tcp/domain] succeeded!
root@cluster0:~# nc -vzw 3  10.96.0.10 53
Connection to 10.96.0.10 53 port [tcp/domain] succeeded!
root@cluster0:~# nc -vzw 3  10.96.0.10 53
Connection to 10.96.0.10 53 port [tcp/domain] succeeded!
root@cluster0:~# nc -vzw 3  10.96.0.10 53
```